# What should be in the end of await-async chain with busy wait/CPU bound code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have this sample code

```
var t = Float();
...
t.Wait();


async Task Float()
{
    while (LoopIsAllowed)
    {
        TryToComplete();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

In this case code run synchronously and I have warning "async method lacks 'await'". I really need to run Float() async so this warning should almost always be considered. As I see it the problem here is that if I call `Float()` and await it latter the application will not work as intended and it will stuck on `var t = Float()` instead of `t.Wait()`

But I do not see any way to fix that other than like this:

```
async Task Float()
{
    while (LoopIsAllowed)
    {
        TryToComplete();
        await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500));
    }
}
```

Does this fix have any sense? In terms of memory and processor resources is it fine to call `Task.Run` or is there better way?
As I see it after the fix calling `var t = Float()` will force the code to run synchronously until `await Task.Run` is reached. Then parent code will continue execution until `t.Wait()`. Only then it will continue to iterate through `while (LoopIsAllowed)` loop. And this behavior is exactly what I need.

Is this correct?

EDIT:
What should I do if I do not have any delay in my code at all? And there is no other place to await. Should I just add delay? Or should I analyze code and add Task.Run somewhere around time consuming calculations blocks?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(500);`?

Comment: You should use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0) and `await Task.Delay(500);` as multiple tasks can (and probably are) running on the same thread

Comment: When you use `Task.Run`, you are pulling a thread-pool thread out of the poll and scheduling your work onto that thread.  `Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500));` says, take a thread pool thread, put it completely asleep for a half second, let me know when it wakes up and then put the thread right back into the pool. As everyone has pointed out, use `Task.Delay`.  In general, you should be `async` all the way down and `async` all the way up as well.  Your `t = Float(); t.Wait();` code should really be in an `async` method as well: `await Float();`

Comment: I've updated title to what I think you are asking (making CPU-bound code async) and resolved as duplicate of existing question on the topic. If you asking something else or duplicated does not address your question - please [edit] the question to clarify that and then the question possible will be re-opened for more answers.

Comment: Marked as duplicate: [Why use C# async/await for CPU-bound tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928678/why-use-c-sharp-async-await-for-cpu-bound-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `Thread.Sleep` in async method.

use `await Task.Delay();` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

```
async Task Float()
{
    while (LoopIsAllowed)
    {
        TryToComplete();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

and in main method use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `wait`

```
var t = Float().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Preferably await the call to `Float` instead of using either, but yeah, `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is preferred if you can't refactor your calling code to be async

Comment: What should I do if I do not have delay in my code at all? And there is no other place to await. Should I add delay? Or should I analyze code and add Task.Run somewhere where there are some long calculations?

Comment: @binariti if you do not have delay in your code, you don't need to use `Task` and `async`.
another options is `await Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: @binariti Then you should have `void Float()`, not have any funny business it it, and should have `var t = Task.Run(() => Float())` in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about my description of code flow in the question. Is it correct?

Comment: @binariti No, nothing will stop the parent from resuming as soon as the `Float` task is created. Which is what you should want in the first place. If you want to create a task in a suspended state and let it start actual work only after a certain event, well, that can be done too, but it's much easier to just create the task after it's known it's safe to start.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to introduce parallelism, the best place to offload synchronous work to the `ThreadPool` by using the `Task.Run` method is the upper level possible. This means that hiding `Task.Run`s deep inside method chains should generally be avoided. The reasoning is explained in this article: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) In your case the (not aptly named) `Float` method does synchronous work, so it should be a synchronous method with a `void` return type. You could then offload it to the `ThreadPool` like this:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => Float());
//...
t.Wait();
```

The `Task.Run` is a [clever little method](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) that handles synchronous and asynchronous delegates (delegates with `Task` return type) equally well. So if you decide later to improve the  efficiency (regarding utilization of threads) of the `Float` method by converting it to a mixed sync-async method, you can do it without changing anything in the calling site (beyond the name of the method that should now have the `Async` suffix):

```
async Task FloatAsync()
{
    while (LoopIsAllowed) // Potential code smell here. Is the LoopIsAllowed volatile?
    {
        TryToComplete();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => FloatAsync());
//...
t.Wait();
```